Stripe Integration Subscriptions
How to integrate Stripe subscriptions in y app? Is this good flow?
From frontend i call direclty this.stripe.createPaymentMethod and pass card details to stripe.
Than i call BE route ‘/create-subscription’ and pass to it PaymentMethodID, price, subscription interval etc and details about customer.
Then Be will create customer and sub for him.
Price is dynamic and it is calucalted based on what user defined in system. I can not have fixed price in stripe and just pass some priceID to stripe. I need to pass from FE price to BE. But it is not good i guess?
What do you think about this whole flow?
Importan thing is that form should be embeded.
I am FE developer and i need to find the best way how to handle this integration. They expect that from me.

Asking for opinions is not tolerated very well on this site. If that flow works for your business logic, then I guess it is OK. You can use the stripe API to build the invoice/subscription using your front end to configure it, then redirect the user to stripe to accept and pay for it. If it works, then that is good enough, you have to code it after all. What is best in this case is subjective and would require more information to give you a better answer than that.

And to clarify, Stripe has their official Subscription Doc in which the flow is different from yours: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions

@orakaro but their flow is for checkout. I need embeded form.

I don't personally agree with this flow, mainly because it's not optimized for 3DSecure authentication.
The createPaymentMethod method does not authenticate the card. When you're in the backend and create your Subscription with the payment method ID, what do you do if the first payment of the Subscription requires 3DSecure authentication? The only way would be to go back to FE and confirm the payment using the confirmCardPayment method.
There are two ways to implement Subscriptions with a custom form with this in mind:

Following Stripe's documentation
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?platform=web&ui=elements
This creates the Subscription first, and collects the payment method by confirming the first payment of said Subscription.

You might not like that - a lot of users prefer not creating the Subscription until they know they collected the payment method.

In that case, collect the payment method with a Setup Intent first (which will handle 3DS if required)
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements
Then create your Subscription with the setup_intent.payment_method. Make sure you set off_session=true in your Subscription create so that Stripe knows the first payment of the Subscription isn't intended to be made on session and should therefore be exempted from authentication.

About having variable pricing, you can create prices inline with your Subscription create call (no need to create the price separately) using the price_data array.
Stripe seems to have removed all guide docs about this array for Subscriptions, but you can see it being used for Stripe Checkout here:
https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=stripe-hosted#redirect-customers
Note that for Subscriptions, the product_data array isn't supported - you will still need a Product object.
